# How do I find the equation of a line that passes through point and two skew lines

Tags: vectors

This is not an orthogonal line cutting through two skew lines at a shortest possible distance. 
This is just some line cutting those skew lines at some angle and also going through a point.

Skew line 1 =

x = 2l - 7

y = 3l - 14

z = l

Skew line 2 =

x = 3m - 10

y = 2m - 6

z = m

Point (1,2,0).

Thanks a lot in advance. I want to understand how this works :).

Comment: Another point of the line is obtained intersecting one of the skew lines with the plane passing through the given point and parallel to the other skew line.

Answer (score 1):

The line has to lie both in the plane spanned by the point and the first line and the plane spanned by the point and the second line, so one option is to find the result by intersecting these two planes.

Comment: Will those two planes not be the same? I did not quite understand what you said...

Comment: @Deo Read 1.18 on p. 7 of this [pdf](http://math.uni.lodz.pl/~maczar/gk/prasolov-stereometry.pdf) by Prasolov.

Comment: @Deo No, the two planes are not the same. A point and a line determines a plane. The same point with another line (usually) determines another plane.